# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when creating a instance of class

Tags: python, syntax, python-idle

I run this code in Python shell 3.3.2, but it gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
class Animal(object):
    """Makes cute animals."""
    is_alive = True
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def description(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.age)

hippo = Animal("2312",21)#error occurs in that line
hippo.description()
```

I'm a newbie in Python and I don't know how fix this code.

[image: Screenshot from IDLE]

Comment: Your code works fine. http://ideone.com/PSdx8P

Comment: I have tried your code and there is no error.

Comment: Is this in Codecademy? Because their IDLE can get very buggy...

Comment: @Haidro the code is from Codecademy, but I run it in my Python IDLE(download from the official website)

Comment: Ah okay. Have fun learning from codecademy :).

Comment: Instead of writing(or pasting) the whole code in interpreter write it in a file and you can execute that file from IDLE by pressing F5.

Comment: IDLE is seriously buggy, so always always retest code in plain Python shell before declaring it bad. Also, a good habit to put space between the comment `hippo = Animal("2312",21)#error occurs in that line`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't indent your code properly. The body of your methods is indented correctly, but you forgot to indent the doc string, and the `def` statement for your methods, in addition to the `is_alive = True` statement. If you type it in IDLE like this, it will work:

```
>>> class Animal(object):
...     """Makes cute animals."""
...     is_alive = True
...     def __init__(self, name, age):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
...     def description(self):
...         print(self.name)
...         print(self.age)
...
>>> hippo = Animal("2312", 21)
>>> hippo.description()
2312
21
```

The body of a block statement is anything that comes after a `:`, and it needs to be properly indented. for example:

```
if 'a' == 'b':
    print('This will never print')
else:
    print('Of course a is not equal to b!')
```

If you type it like this:

```
if 'a' == 'b':
print('This will never print')
else:
print('Of course a is not equal to b!')
```

It is not valid Python syntax.